# JQuery - switch focus between input on enter according tabindex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following structure on page

```
<div id="testDialog" class="dialogContent">
<form:form action="#" id="testForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>one</td>
            <td><input id="c1" type="text" maxlength="45" tabindex="49"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>two</td>
            <td><input id="c2" type="text" maxlength="8" tabindex="50"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>three</td>
            <td><input id="c3" type="text" maxlength="8" tabindex="51"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>four</td>
            <td><input id="c4" type="text" maxlength="8" tabindex="52"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="button" tabindex="53">Confirm</button></td>
            <td><button type="button" tabindex="54">Cancel</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</div>
```

I need to switch focus between inputs and buttons on enter press. Order of switching should be according tab index. And switching should be cyclically within form, e.g. if focus set on 'Cancel' button, next enter will set focus on first input in this example.
I will be appreciate a lot for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var $targets = $('#testForm').find('input, button'),
    steps = $targets.map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('tabindex');
    }).get();

$('#testForm').on('keypress', 'input, button', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var current = $.inArray($(this).attr('tabindex'), steps),
            next = steps[++current % steps.length];
        $targets.filter('[tabindex="' + next + '"]').focus();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BHA9g/2/

It's also important that <kbd>Enter</kbd> cycles correctly starting from any field, not only the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, great solution. But seems it doesn't consider tabindex order (I tried to change tabindex ordering). And I try to add the same behavior for 'tab' (if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 9)) unfortunately it doesn't switch cyclically for 'tab' enter. Could you help to find out?

Comment: changing .get() to .sort() in the steps definition makes it respect tabindex order.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to add a class called 'TabOnEnter' to the fields where you want to cycle on enter.

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".TabOnEnter" , function(e)
      {

        if( e.keyCode ==  13 )
        {
           var nextElement = $('input[tabindex="' + (this.tabIndex+1)  + '"]');

           if(nextElement.length )// this is for next element
            nextElement.focus();
           else
             $('input[tabindex="1"]').focus();  //this is for first element
        }   
      });​
```